# .htaccess rewrite URL with a question mark "?"

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

My aim is this URL:

```
component/users/?view=registration
```

To:

```
registration.html
```

the `.htaccess` is in the folder mysite of the website.

i tried this:

```
RewriteBase /mysite
RewriteRule ^component/users/?view=registration$ registration.html$ [R=301,L]
```

But i doesnt work...

When i try this:

```
RewriteRule ^component/users/_view=registration$ registration.html$ [R=301,L]
```

it works very well.

So how can i fix this problem with the question mark. I already read thats [it is not a part of the URL](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html#rewriterule) (its appended). I have read that i have to use something like querystring, but i didn't really understand the syntax.

Maybe someone could write the solution of this problem? Would be awesome =)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to use `%{QUERY_STRING}` to capture the query string data:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^component/users/?$ %1.html? [R=301,L]
```

The above rule/condition will take the value of the query string view and use it to form your redirect if the path `component/users` matches.

Comment: thanks for the answer but it doesnt work.

this is what i get:

http://localhost/mysite/registration.html?view=registration

when i type:

http://localhost/mysite/component/users/?view=registration

do you have an idea how this "?view=registration" can be removed?

Comment: @Bardock Please tell me how can its remove the "?view=registration" ?

Comment: i bet you're using `$1` instead of `%1`. Look carefully at the answer, it says to use `%1` which will match the correct thing. I'm not sure why, but in my case $1 matches the whole rule as well...

Comment: @anarcat $ is used to capture the left hand of the RewriteRule while % is used to capture the parameters coming from the RewriteCond https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/intro.html

Comment: yeah, i know that, but there's no group on the left side!

Answer (score -3):

```
RewriteRule ^component/users/\?view=registration$ registration.html$ [R=301,L]
```

You need a \ because ? is part of a regular expression. To Use it as a string u need to escape it with a \

Linktip: http://ole.michelsen.dk/tools/regex.html

Comment: doesnt work. It still redirects me to localhost/mysite/component/users/?view=registration :(