# .htaccess rewrite URL with a question mark “?” only for 1 specific URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

I already started a topic some weeks ago.
But I got now a new problem that is very similar to the old problem: [.htaccess rewrite URL with a question mark "?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18543194/htaccess-rewrite-url-with-a-question-mark)

My aim was this URL:

```
/mysite/component/users/?view=registration
```

Rewrite into this new URL:

```
mysite/registration.html
```

My current `.htaccess` got this code:

```
RewriteBase /mysite

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^component/users/?$ %1.html? [R=301,L]
```

It worked very fine.

But then I noticed that this config concerns all URL that starts like this:

```
/mysite/component/users/?view=
```

For example this config would also concern an URL like this:

```
/mysite/component/users/?view=remind
```

This is what I don't want

I only want this URL rewritten:

```
localhost/mysite/component/users/?view=registration
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
RewriteBase /mysite

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=(registration)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^component/users/$ %1.html? [R=301,L]
```

If you want it to work only for `registration` then you can specify that instead a catchall regex.

**Also keep in mind that since you had it with a global permanent redirect you may need to clear your browser cache or use a different browser to instantly see the changes.**

Comment: awesome mate, it works!!
thank you very much! unfortunately i am not able to vote +1 .