# How can I remove this directory/folder from url with htaccess rewrite?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory, url-rewriting

My aim is:

```
domain.com/folder
```

rewrite ->

```
domain.com
```

this shall concern ALL links inside that site.
I mean on the site are links like:

```
domain.com/folder/forum.html
domain.com/folder/community.html
```

etc.

This is my aim:

```
domain.com/forum.html
domain.com/community.html
```

etc.

and its very important that the "folder" is never in the url in the adressbar visible.

I tried already many codes but I couldnt really solve this problem.
My best try was with this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)folder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder/$1 [L]
```

If I enter

```
 domain.com
```

I get the content of

```
 domain.com/folder
```

displayed, what is correct ("folder" is not in the url shown). But when i click on some links of the site like: domain.com/folder/community.html then I can see again "folder" in the url, but I want that it becomes ALWAYS removed.

here is my site:

```
thewedgiecommunity.x10.mx/wedgiecommunity/
```

My aim is to remove the "wedgiecommunity" (=folder)
This link is working

```
  thewedgiecommunity.x10.mx/
```

But when you click on Community (

```
 thewedgiecommunity.x10.mx/wedgiecommunity/community.html
```

) then i get again "wedgiecommunity" in the URL.

Would be awesome when someone could help me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this code:

**Goes in DOCUMENT_ROOT/wedgiecommunity/.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+wedgiecommunity([^\s]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

**Goes in DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^/?wedgiecommunity wedgiecommunity%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: doesnt work. Its still the same with this code.
When I go to thewedgiecommunity.x10.mx/wedgiecommunity/community.html
I still see the "wedgiecommunity" (=folder) in the URL.l

Comment: +1 but I think you're catching an extra `/` in your condition (in the `%1` capture group).

Comment: @Bardock: Q1. Is this the only .htaccess or do you have another in wedgiecommunity? Q2. Is this the only code in this .htaccess? If you have some other code then please post it in question? Q3. What is location of above .htaccess?

Comment: A1: yes I have another .htaccess, in wedgiecommunity.
But I cant post all its content here, because of char limit.
A2: yes, I completely replaced the old code with this code.
A3: its in the public_html folder
I can give you FTP Access if you think it helps.

Comment: hmm okey, it removes now the wedgiecommunity everywhere. but now i get 404 Error Codes on the website... I m really confused now.
Maybe its practical impossible what I want?

Comment: i dont know if its relevant, but this site is based on the CMS Joomla and its SEF Function is activated. The SEF Rules are in the wedgiecommunity/.htaccess

Comment: You should be all set now. Make sure to clear Joomla cache and browser cache before you start testing. Site is accessible using `http://thewedgiecommunity.x10.mx` and other pages as `http://thewedgiecommunity.x10.mx/about/rules.html`

Comment: AWESOME MATE! You did it!
There is now only one thing missing. Before I gave you the FTP account I removed this code from wedgiecommunity/.htaccess

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=(registration)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^component/users/$ %1.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^community/register.html registration.html [R=301,L]

(RewriteBase was also /wedgiecommunity)

now I have added this rules again, but they dont work anymore.

Background: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884082/htaccess-rewrite-url-with-a-question-mark-only-for-1-specific-url

Comment: Now when I click
    http://thewedgiecommunity.x10.mx/component/users/?view=registration

I get 
    http://thewedgiecommunity.x10.mx/wedgiecommunity/registration.html

But my aim is:
     http://thewedgiecommunity.x10.mx/registration.html

the same belongs to the other rule.
I have modified the .htaccess. Maybe you can check it via FTP?

Comment: Sorry I just came online. Let me check the rules and revert back.

Comment: I have fixed your `.htaccess` for both of these 2 rules. Check them out.

Comment: You nearly fixed it :) .

The last rule is still wrong.
it redirected me to thewedgiecommunity.x10.mx/register.html
aim is:  thewedgiecommunity.x10.mx/registration.html

I have changed the FTP Account Credentials, but at the moment the webhost got some internal server problems. If they are again online I will send you the FTP Account.

And THANK YOU VERY VERY MUCH FOR HELPING SO MUCH!!!!!!!!

Comment: hey,
support of my webhost said that the .htaccess causes the 500 internal server error. could you please fix it :) ?
I have made a new FTP Account... but how can I send you the credentials in private?

Comment: send me an email `anubhava[AT]aol[DOT]com` and I will take a look

Comment: he mate, I think I have found a workaround.
These htaccess rules were just one of a possible solution of my originally problem. I didnt thought that it would be complicated like that :) . But i am nearly to fix it on an other way.
Nevertheless BIG THANK YOU!!! So shall I mark your post as the right answer? A shame that i cant give you reputation :S

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule to "remove" the folder from the URL when it is accessed directly via the browser:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /wedgiecommunity/
RewriteRule ^wedgiecommunity/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Then your other rule will handle the rest.

Comment: doesnt work. Its still the same with this code.
When I go to thewedgiecommunity.x10.mx/wedgiecommunity/community.html
I still see the "wedgiecommunity" (=folder) in the URL.