# Use .htaccess to remove directory folder from URL

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This type of question has been asked in SO before but the offered solutions do not work for me. [How can I remove this directory/folder from url with htaccess rewrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389344/how-can-i-remove-this-directory-folder-from-url-with-htaccess-rewrite)

I have a multi site wordpress install that I have inherited and it has a single .htaccess file in the root directory of the site.

I need to do a global redirect on all URLs like this `http:thewebsite.com/jol/blog/author/myles/` to go to `http:thewebsite.com/jol/author/myles/`

So far I have tried this code in the .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# Remove subdirectory of "blog" from URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /blog/
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

and this code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /blog/
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

and lastly, this code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

and absolutely none of them work at all. The only thing that has been successful so far is targeting each URL individually and performing a redirect, which is...PAINFUL.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: The pattern `^blog/` would fail because your URLs start with `jol/`

Comment: Thanks! That makes so much sense when I look at it now. How would i target the next child directory of 'blog' then?

Comment: Try this `RewriteRule ^(.*(?=blog/))blog/(.*)$ $1$2 [NC,L,R=301]`

Comment: You sir... are my hero!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules which you tried were not working because you had had: `^blog/` in your patterns. Since the URLs you wanted to rewrite are of the form `jol/blog/...`, the rule should be updated.

Assuming that `jol` may vary; use the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+/(?=blog/))blog/(.*)$ $1$2 [R=301,L,NC]
```

and if `jol` will always be in the rules, just use that:

```
RewriteRule ^jol/blog/(.*)$ jol/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```