# Mod_rewrite: Question mark in RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am dealing with an API that is accessing an URL on my website and adding "/?parameter=value" to the url. I want my htaccess to handle this request and only keep the parameter's value. I want to keep it simple.

```
RewriteRule ^my-url/\?parameter=(.*)$ controller.php?parameter=$1

RewriteRule ^my-url/.parameter=(.*)$ controller.php?parameter=$1
```

Both of the above does not work.
There seem to be an issue handling the question mark.

Comment: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18543194/57091)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `RewriteCond` to match QUERY_STRING:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^parameter=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^my-url/?$ controller.php?parameter=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Anyway to do it without RewriteCond, using RewriteRule only? If not, why isn't it possible?

Comment: It is because `RewriteRule` matches REQUEST_URI only. Anything after `?` is called query string and that can be matched ONLY using `RewriteCond`. Why do you not want to use `RewriteCond`?

Comment: Thanks that make sense. One quick question: why use the flags QSA. It seems to be working with them too.

Comment: Yes `QSA` isn't probably needed in this case. `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one. You can sure take it out.

Comment: Thanks anubhava for the support.

Comment: Is there a reason `^parameter=([^&]+)` doesn't end with a `$`?

Comment: Yes, that is to take care of additional parameters in this query string.