# Apache2: Rewrite url containing question mark

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using `Apache 2.4.7`. I use `mod_rewrite` to alter some urls.

I want to rewrite `http://example.com/servicename/oldpage?id=abc`to `http://example.com/servicename/newpage`.

Other similar rewrites work so I belive the `?` inside url is causing problems.
I have tried escaping it with `\`.

This works as there is no `?` in url:

`RewriteRule ^/servicename/old /servicename/new`

But these don't work:

`RewriteRule ^/servicename/oldpage?id=abc /servicename/newpage`

`RewriteRule ^/servicename/oldpage\?id=abc /servicename/newpage`

I have also tried using `RewriteCond` from examples like this: [.htaccess rewrite URL with a question mark "?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18543194/htaccess-rewrite-url-with-a-question-mark) but I didn't manage to get them work.

How should rewrite url that contains question mark?

EDIT: I tried solutions given in [Match Question Mark in mod_rewrite rule regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822421/match-question-mark-in-mod-rewrite-rule-regex) but was not able to make them work for me. That question is about preserving query string when rewrite while I want to remove it when rewriting.

Comment: Do you want the rewrite to depend on content of `id=` query string, or you just need it removed from request sent to newpage?

Comment: I want it removed, not caring of its contents.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Match Question Mark in mod\_rewrite rule regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822421/match-question-mark-in-mod-rewrite-rule-regex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RewriteRule pattern is matched against the part of the URL after the hostname and port, and before the query string.

When the requested URI contains a query string, and the target URI does not, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to copy that query string to the target URI. Using the [QSD] flag causes the query string to be discarded.

So, this should work:

```
RewriteRule ^/servicename/oldpage /servicename/newpage [QSD]
```